# How can I pass a char null in a Stored Procedure method in C# 3.0?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to make this SP run:

```
myDataContext.InsertEvent(codEvent, dateOfEvent, statusOfEvent);
```

codEvent is an int; dateOfEvent is a DateTime; statusOfEvent is a char.

The problem is Visual Studio is throwing an error if I pass a statusOfEvent null. And, my SP accpts nullable char just like my table.

I've tried to do this too:

```
char? statusOfEvent= null;
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(f["statusOfEvent"]))
           statusOfEvent= Convert.ToChar(f["statusOfEvent"]);
```

But it also throws an error...

thanks!!

I've tried to do this ternary expression:

```
!String.IsNullOrEmpty(f["statusOfEvent"]) ? Convert.ToChar(f["statusOfEvent"]) : DBNull.Value
```

But it is says that 'there is no implicit conversion between char and DBNull'

And I also looked at '*.dbml' designer.cs file and my SP method has this line:

```
[Parameter(DbType="Char(1)")] System.Nullable<char> statusOfEvent
```

Comment: Don't edit the dbml designer code directly! use the DBML designer to edit the entities and let the code be autogenerated. Can you provide more details on the error being thrown as it sounds like it should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you need [DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx)[.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) rather than `null`.

**Update**
To use, you would pass it where you might other wise pass `null`. So, assuming that `statusOfEvent` is nullable, you could do the following.

```
myDataContext.InsertEvent(
    codEvent,
    dateOfEvent,
    statusOfEvent ?? DBNull.Value);
```

However, `InsertEvent` would need to accept it as a valid input for this parameter. If you're using some .NET support like an XSD dataset to describe the stored procedure. You can modify this to change the parameter to accept `char?` from `char`. Then you should be able to pass `null` and the underlying system will convert this to `DBNull.Value` for you. In that scenario, you can leave the call as:

```
myDataContext.InsertEvent(
    codEvent,
    dateOfEvent,
    statusOfEvent);
```

This should also work with Linq2Sql. To change the stored procedure's representation in your Linq2Sql objects, you need to open your dbml and edit the properties for the stored procedure.

Comment: But how can I use this DBNull?

Comment: Hi Jeff! I'm using LinqToSql! I forgot to mention that!

Answer (score 0):

DBNull.Value is what that database expects...

Here is how I am passing IsActive (which is a nullable boolean) as a parameter...

```
_ExecutedSP = new StoredProcedure("EvaluationType_GetList", base._SPInputOutput);
if (this.IsActive == null)
{
    _ExecutedSP.AddParameter("@IsActive", SqlDbType.Bit, DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
    _ExecutedSP.AddParameter("@IsActive", SqlDbType.Bit, this.IsActive);
}
```